# Opencart 2.0.3.1 - Retrieving data from DB

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

In an Opencart 2.0.3.1 in a custom template, I am trying to retrieve data drom the db. But I don't get any results.

I am trying to get the "product_id" when the "sku" has a special result. How is the code for that? Can anyone help?

I need the product_id from the table oc_product WHERE sku = $variable .

Answer (score 0):

To get product id by sku code, try this

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT product_id FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "product` WHERE `sku` = '".$this->db->escape($variable))."'";

$productId = $query->row[product_id]; // product id
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does that error: 2017-05-12 8:51:17 - PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Loader::$db

Comment: Sorry for the typo mistake. Now check this. Please the code to your model and call from controller.

Comment: Thanks, possibly you can tell me exactly what to put on which file? Because I am really noob and I don´t know ehat to do. Thanks in advance